# How to read ArrayList<String> from a specific row

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to read a specific row and column from an `ArrayList<String>` to display it in a textview.

In a previous activity I read a Firebase table and stored all information selected by the user in an `ArrayList<String>`. I do a `putExtra`, and I recover all data by a `Bundle`. The `ArrayList<String>` recovered seems correct. But now I don't know what to do to read this `ArrayList`.

I've looked at different solutions in Stack Overflow and Github without success.

Have you any idea?

[image]

[Result of ArrayList](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PGbf.png)

Answer (score 2):

From your picture, it seems you don't have an `ArrayList<String>` but rather a `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`

To access it, use `.get(index)`

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> ContenuAnnonceA;
int i=1, j=2;
String s = ContenuAnnonceA.get(i).get(j);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In fact this is my problem,. Indeed, In the previous activity i've defined an  ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>.  I've tried to do a putExtra of my  ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> and then in the last activity, the only solution i've found  is to use a Bundle for the getStringExtra. In this case is not possible to use an ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> but an   ArrayList<String> and i don't know what to do

Comment: @GeorgesGRESSIEN I really don't understand what you want now ^^